# Calculating the lower bound on the chromatic number of a simple graph.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

In a homework assignment, I was told to show that if $G$ is a simple graph, then $\chi(G) \geq \frac{\nu^2}{\nu^2 - 2\varepsilon}$, where $\nu(G)$ is the number of vertices in the graph and $\varepsilon(G)$ is the number of edges in the graph (I include this because I've been told the notation is out of date). I've attempted to do this by induction on both the number of vertices and the number of edges (for a given graph on $\nu$ vertices). Neither seems to be working very well. How should I proceed here?

Comment: I think this problem is just about numbers, not graphs, though I haven't completed it.  Suppose the chromatic number of $G$ is $\chi$ and that $|G|=v$.  Color the graph with $\chi$ colors.  Then we can add an edge between any two non-adjacent differently colored vertices without increasing the chromatic number; that is, it is sufficient to prove this if $G$ is a complete $\chi-$partite graph.  Now it just a matter of counting edges and showing that some inequality holds.  Perhaps Cauchy-Schwarz applies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving for $\varepsilon$, an equivalent statement is
$$
   \varepsilon(G) \le \left(1 - \frac1{\chi(G)}\right)\frac{\nu(G)^2}{2}.
$$
This follows from [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem), since $G$ cannot contain a clique on $\chi(G)+1$ vertices.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't see how this expression is found with Turán's theorem. I see that since $G$ contains no $K_{\chi + 1}$, that the theorem tells us that $\varepsilon(G) \leq \varepsilon(T_{\chi, \nu})$, but I don't see how we get that $\varepsilon(T_{\chi, \nu}) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{\chi}\right)\frac{\nu^2}{2}$. Could you explain why this happens?

Comment: Note: evidently, the statement of Turán's theorem in my book is not the standard statement on Wikipedia. Ours defines $T_{k,\nu}$ to be the complete $k$-partite graph on $\nu$ vertices so that each part has as close to equal numbers of vertices as possible. I'm willing to guess that $\varepsilon$ of this thing is precisely what is given in the statement on Wikipedia. Just adding this for completeness.

Comment: The number of edges in the Turán graph is always at most $\left(1-\frac1r\right)\frac{n^2}{2}$, but sometimes it's slightly smaller due to the rounding. So the statement in your book is slightly stronger (though less convenient to use).